# Html CSS: Have two block elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to position two divs side by side.

Here's the jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/M4t9k/19/

I want the title field to be a left column, it will always have 1 line but its width can change so I cannot set it as a fixed value.

Then, the icons div contains a bunch of icons (a variable number of them).

The idea is that the icons div works as a column next to the title column, with the icons never going under the title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per i understand may be that's you want

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/M4t9k/23/

or

this http://jsfiddle.net/M4t9k/30/

Comment: Yep, that's it, I just don't get why? I mean, I use overflow:hidden to prevent a box's content to show out of it. It's strange to use it this way.

Comment: Read this http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats